# FontFace Do Not Show Any Text

Tags: css

This code is Top of a css file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: BNB;
    src: /* IE6–8 */
/* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
url(../fonts/BKdakBold.eot?#) format(eot), url(../fonts/BKdakBold.woff) format(woff), url(../fonts/BKdakBold.ttf) format(truetype);
/* Saf3—5, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
}
```

This is a css code to show special font...In google chorme any text is hidden at first.
But when  click right and choice "Inspect Element",The text shows!
(or for very light simple pages!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you working on an actual server? Css3 Fonts will not always be downloaded when you are running a webpage from your personal computer. I had that problem multiple times. Upload it to your webserver and see if that helps ;)

Comment: Even on localhost this is a problem. I had websites on my localhost that didnt download the fonts right, and then I uploaded them and they would work, please give it a try. ;)

Comment: Tnaks for the answer :)

Comment: Hahaha, you're welcome. You didn't see that coming :p